# Scripts stop working after gulp concat

Tags: javascript, gulp, concatenation

When creating a website, I used to link all my scripts individually and everything worked fine. I am now learning to use gulp and noticed that after I concatenate my JS files, some scripts stop working (again, they all work when loaded individually).

The only thing I found on the net is that I might have to concatenate files in a certain order. I tried changing the order in the gulpfile.js task to no avail. I tried removing files one by one in the gulpfile.js task to no avail.

Also, I keep Modernizr and JQuery always in the header and loaded individually (they are NOT concatenated with the others) while the concatenated JS file is in the footer, therefore loaded after.

HTML file looks something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <meta ...>
        <link...>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/scripts/modernizr.js"></script>

        <title>Some Title</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    WEBSITE CONTENT

        <script src="assets/scripts/scripts.min.js"></script> /*Concatenated file*/

    </body>
</html>
```

My gulp task (gulpfile.js) looks like this (I've separated the scripts to concatenate in an array so you guys can see the files) :

```
gulp.task('js', function(){
  return gulp.src([
      'assets/scripts/base/bootstrap.js',
      'assets/scripts/base/retina.js',
      'assets/scripts/base/smoothscroll.js',
      'assets/scripts/base/waypoints.js',
      'assets/scripts/base/wow.js',
      'assets/scripts/plugins/bootstrap.filestyle.js',
      'assets/scripts/plugins/jquery.counterup.js',
      'assets/scripts/plugins/jquery.matchHeight.js',
      'assets/scripts/plugins/lightcase.js',
      'assets/scripts/plugins/slick.js',
      'assets/scripts/plugins/global.js'
  ])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/scripts/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});
```

For now, the scripts that I noted stopped working were the lighcase.js (lightbox), jquery.matchHeight.js (matching column height) and slick.js (slider).

Edit : No errors on my console. Only the message "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.0".

Any help would be appreciated. After one week of trying to find the logic behind this issue, I give up lol. Help a noob!

Comment: So, do they silently "stop working"? Or may be some errors are thrown in the console?

Comment: The only message I have on my console is : JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.0.

But no red error alerts.

Comment: Well, verify that your script is even being loaded. Then set a breakpoint in the entry point, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer matmo. How would you translate "set a breakpoint in the entry point" in noobish?

Comment: *"I might have to concatenate files in a certain order"* - You **definitely** have to concatenate the files in a certain order, assuming any of the files are dependent on any others (e.g., library X plugins have to come after library X core). It should work if you concatenate them in the same order that you were including them when using individual `<script>` tags.

Comment: @nnnnnn Beleive it or not, I did exactly that. And it still didnt work. :S

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the `scripts.min.js` to see if it looks OK? Maybe temporarily skip the minimise/uglify step so that you can inspect the combined file output more easily.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah Im currently in Chrome Dev Tool doing some breakpoint debugging. Just noticed that some scripts did not concatenate. That would explain alot. Found out that path for global.js file was wrong in gulpfile.js, so fixed that. But 4 other js files did not concatenate and their paths in gulpfile.js are fine. What could explain that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: NVM all the scripts are there, just didnt see 'em all because they showed inline. It was only my global.js path that was wrong... works now. So sorry and thx much. :)

Answer (score 0):

So much work to debug and it was only my global.js path that was wrong in my gulpfile task.

```
'assets/scripts/plugins/global.js'
```

was supposed to be:

```
'assets/scripts/base/global.js'
```